# DDMS Event Log: runLogService got "com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed"

Tags: android, adb, ddms

So, I tried to improve standalone DDMS, when checking the Event Log panel/tab. I got this error:

```
11:09:45 E/EventLog: closed
com.android.ddmlib.AdbCommandRejectedException: closed
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.runLogService(AdbHelper.java:579)
at com.android.ddmlib.AdbHelper.runEventLogService(AdbHelper.java:548)
at com.android.ddmlib.Device.runEventLogService(Device.java:584)
at com.android.ddmuilib.log.event.EventLogPanel$8.run(EventLogPanel.java:461)
```

So far, I tried using emulator fw 2.3.3 (API 10) and it's works, but doesn't work for fw 6.0 (API 23).

So far I've found:
On fw 2.3.3 API 10:
- it has file path `/dev/log/events`
- when I pull the file, it seems log events that I need

On fw 6.0 API 23:
- it doesn't has file path `/dev/log/events`, instead it moved to `/dev/input/event0` or `dev/input/event1`
- when I pull the file, it has 0 size, means it is an empty file

Some device has `/dev/log/events` even it fw 6.0 API 23 (in my case Samsung SM-A500F). When manually pull, it's not empty, but still it has adb rejection error "closed".

What I done so far:
- change the command from `byte[] request = formAdbRequest("log:" + logName);` to: `byte[] request = formAdbRequest("input:event0");` -> still get the "Closed" error
- change the command to: `byte[] request = formAdbRequest("shell:logcat -v threadtime -b " + logName);` -> the "Closed" error is gone, but the result data cannot be parsed, it has different format

```
public static void runLogService(InetSocketAddress adbSockAddr, Device device, String logName,
        LogReceiver rcvr) throws TimeoutException, AdbCommandRejectedException, IOException {
    SocketChannel adbChan = null;

    try {
        adbChan = SocketChannel.open(adbSockAddr);
        adbChan.configureBlocking(false);

        // if the device is not -1, then we first tell adb we're looking to talk
        // to a specific device
        setDevice(adbChan, device);

        byte[] request = formAdbRequest("log:" + logName);
        write(adbChan, request);

        AdbResponse resp = readAdbResponse(adbChan, false /* readDiagString */);
        if (!resp.okay) {
            throw new AdbCommandRejectedException(resp.message);
        }

        byte[] data = new byte[16384];
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(data);
        while (true) {
            int count;

            if (rcvr != null && rcvr.isCancelled()) {
                break;
            }

            count = adbChan.read(buf);
            if (count < 0) {
                break;
            } else if (count == 0) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(WAIT_TIME * 5);
                } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
                }
            } else {
                if (rcvr != null) {
                    rcvr.parseNewData(buf.array(), buf.arrayOffset(), buf.position());
                }
                buf.rewind();
            }
        }
    } finally {
        if (adbChan != null) {
            adbChan.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm afraid that the system events log is no longer can be read through `log:events`, but I still couldn't find the documents for this.

Any comments are highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.